# Recursice JSONB join in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to expand existing system to allow self-referencing "foreighn key" relationships based on values in  JSONB. I'll give an example for beter understanding

```
|  ID  |            DATA                                        |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |{building_id: 1, building_name: 'Office 1'}             |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  2   |{building_id: 2, building_name: 'Office 2'}             |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  3   |{building_id: 1, full_name: 'John Doe', calary: 3000}   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  4   |{building_id: 1, full_name: 'Alex Smit', calary: 2000}  |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  5   |{building_id: 1, full_name: 'Anna Birkin', calary: 2500}|
```

I tried using `jsonb_array_elements_text` but i need new data to be combined in single JSON field like this

```
|  ID  |            DATA                                                                     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |{building_id: 1, building_name: 'Office 1', full_name: 'John Doe', calary: 3000}     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  2   |{building_id: 1, building_name: 'Office 1', full_name: 'Alex Smit', calary: 2000}    |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  3   |{building_id: 2, building_name: 'Office 2', , full_name: 'Anna Birkin', calary: 2500}|
```

I am wondering whether it is even possible

Comment: Foreign keys in JSON? You are lost. Redesign the database using regular columns for foreign keys.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, the problem is that objects in JSON field may vary and are set by end user and I can't imagine creating new tables for each of them

Comment: But `building_id` doesn't seem to vary, so that could be a regular column.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it was just an exapmle, it can be anything that suets to be a foreighn key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Anna Birkin is in building_id 2 and these different object types are consistent enough to determine types by the presence of keys, try something like this:

```
select b.data || p.data as result
  from really_bad_idea b
       join really_bad_idea p on p.data->'building_id' = b.data->'building_id'
 where b.data ? 'building_name'
   and p.data ? 'full_name';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4a892631e61f4c0c22b305c9e21f41da)*